# Beginner: Responsive design, can´t get it to work :(

Tags: html, css

Hey guys ok here is my curenty website layout

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="sidr">     
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/iconmonstr-magnifier-icon-24.png" width="24" height="24" alt=""/> Concepts</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Out Now</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#simple-menu').sidr();
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col col-12">   
           <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">
                <div class="menu"> </div>
           </a>
           SWITCHYARD 
           <div class="search"> </div>
        </div>

   <a href="#"> 
   <div class="col col-13"> 
     <div class="ghost-btn">
        <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div>
        <div class="text_18">Why Her Will Dominate UI Design</div>
     </div>

   </div></a>

</div>   

<div class="container">
  <div class="row_1" >

    <div class="col col-41">

   <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="artikel_template.html"> <div class="ghost-btn-small">  <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div> </div>  </a>       

        </div>

    <div class="col col-42">

    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="artikel_template.html"> <div class="ghost-btn-small">  <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div> </div></a><br>
        </div>


    <div class="col col-43">

    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="artikel_template.html"><div class="ghost-btn-small">  <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div> </div> </a><br>
        </div>

    <div class="col col-44">

    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="artikel_template.html"><div class="ghost-btn-small">  <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div> </div></a><br>
        </div>

    <div class="col col-45">

    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="artikel_template.html"><div class="ghost-btn-small">  <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div> </div></a><br>
        </div>

    <div class="col col-46">

    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="artikel_template.html"><div class="ghost-btn-small">  <div class="text_14">Feature Article</div> </div></a><br>
        </div>

   <a href="#0" class="cd-top">Top</a>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

**And CSS**

```
   /* CSS Document */

* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

/* << Die sachen beim sternchen sollten immer rein */

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
         background:#FFF;
}

.container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;    
}

.row {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }

.col {
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
    }

.col-1 {
    width:60px;
}

.col-2 {
    width:140px;
}

.col-3 {
    width:220px;
}

/* Artikel Content */

.col-41 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#B04143;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
}

.col-42 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#B04143;
}

.col-43 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#B04143;
}

.col-44 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#B04143;
}

.col-45 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#B04143;
}

.col-46 {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    z-index:-100;
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#B04143;
}

.col-11 {
    width:860px;
    background-color:#B04143;
}

.col-12 {
    width:940px;
    height:50px;
    font-family: "proxima-nova"; 
    color:white;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size:27px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:10px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#B04143;    
}

.col-13 {
    width:940px;
    height:495px;
    margin-top:0px;
    background-color:#B04143;
    text-align: center;    
}

.row_1{
    margin:0px;
}

.newstext {
    height:50px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family: "proxima-nova";
    padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#f1e39b;
}

.btn{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background-color:#f1e39b;
border-radius:5px;
z-index:100;
bottom: 20px;
left: 20px; 
position: absolute;
}

.menu{
width:24px;
height:24px;
background-image:url(images/iconmonstr-menu-icon-24.png);
z-index:100;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}

.search{
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background-image:url(images/iconmonstr-magnifier-icon-24.png);
    z-index:100;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.feature{
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#f1e39b;
    float:right;
    padding:5px;}

.text_18{
    font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro";
    font-size:18pt; 
}

.text_14{
    font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro";
    font-size:14pt;
    margin-top:2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {

  .cd-top {
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }

.container {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.col{
    background-color:#0F3;
}

.col-12 {
    width: 480px;
    height:135px;

}

.col-13 {
    width: 480px;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:40px;
}

.text_18{
    font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro";
    font-size:12pt;
}

.text_14{
    font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro";
    font-size:9pt;
    margin-top:2px;
}

/* Ghost Button */

.ghost-btn {

  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 200px auto 0 auto;

  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 90px;
  width:50%;
  line-height: 30%;
  color: #fff;

}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  .cd-top {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
  }

.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;  
}

.col{
    background-color:#0F3;
}

.col-4 {
    width: 40%;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:20px; 
}
.col-12 {
    width: 50%;
    height:135px;
    font-family: "proxima-nova"; 
    color:white;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    font-size:50%px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url(images/frosted.jpg);
    padding-top:10px; 
    text-align: center;
}    

.col-13 {
    width: 50%;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:40px;   
}
```

You see I'm working with media queries. And I need  a "lower" ipad version and a phone version of the website. The desktop version has 3 big columns and i need this to be 1 for the iphone version. However I didn´t get this to work at all. Do you guys have any idea how to get this design to be "responsive"?

**Here is a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/9zS2y/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

to

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zS2y/1/)

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)